# How to change the base URL in Tomcat when deployed on docker

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-compose

I'm pulling a docker image that has an app running on Tomcat 8.5 base image. I'd like to expose a different port (8080 is already in use on the docker machine) and use the docker machine's DHCP name to handle request. I deploy the service using docker compose like so:

```
services:                             
  erddap-server:                      
    image: axiom/docker-erddap # Based off of Tomcat 8.5'ish
    container_name: erddap-server
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    environment:
      - ERDDAP_MIN_MEMORY=1G
      - ERDDAP_MAX_MEMORY=2G
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: unless-stopped
```

When I navigate to *http://my-docker-server.com:8081/my_app* it works fine. If I then click a link in the app it automatically redirects me to *http://localhost:8080/my_app/my_link* which fails since that's pointing to the wrong machine.

Any ideas on what to change? There must be a way to specify the hostname/base url/root url or whatever it's actually called but I can't find it. If there's a way to configure this via an env variable then that would be first prize.

CLARIFICATION:
Taking a look at the server.xml config file for any mention of "localhost" or "8080" shows this:

```
Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    <Connector server="Apache" secure="true" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
```

And

```
<Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
```

Comment: Unless you set `proxyName="localhost"` and `proxyPort="8080"` in your `server.xml` (by default it is unset), this seems to be a bug in your application. Do you have access to the application's code?

Comment: I did a quick grep on the server.xml file and the only "localhost" or "8080" I could find. Not enough space here so I'll add them to the question.

Comment: Your configuration is correct, so your application must incorrectly generate links. A well written servlet application should use [`ServletRequest#getServerName`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequest#getServerName--) and `getServerPort` to generate links. Your application apparently does something else.

Comment: It might well use those but I'm a little unsure that a docker implementation would return the correct port and server name. I'll try to override the base URL and port definitions. 

I'm not too interested in digging around the code, I'd rather just use the docker image as-is. Maybe sticking a nginx proxy in front of it would be a compromise solution.

Comment: You are correct. It's an application specific thing rather than a Docker or Tomcat thing. There is a bunch of "must change" variables buried in an xml file for the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an erddap application specific problem. The <base_url> item in the /usr/local/tomcat/content/erddap/setup.xml file needs to be changed to reflect the machine/container name. It's set to default to localhost:8080.

In my case I changed it to:

```
<baseUrl>http://my-docker-server.com:8081</baseUrl>
```

and then used it as docker bind mount:

```
volumes: 
      - erddap-data:/erddapData 
      - ./my_erddap_setup.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/content/erddap/setup.xml
```

A better solution would be to have it completely configured by .env vars but this works.